# How to prevent rewrite :hover on .click action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need :hover and .click work together.

```
<div class="d">...</div>

$('.d').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().find('.d').css('background-color', 'white');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
});
```

and css:

```css
.d {
    background-color: white;
}
.d:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

When I click on the div hover effect disappear.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nx4CV/

Comment: Don’t set a CSS property directly via JS – set a class name instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also just use:

```
$('.d').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.d').css('background-color', '');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
});
```

to "remove" the background style from the element style.

from: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value

> Setting the value of a style property to an empty string — e.g. $( "#mydiv" ).css( "color", "" ) — removes that property from an element if it has already been directly applied, whether in the HTML style attribute, through jQuery's .css() method, or through direct DOM manipulation of the style property.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a class when `div` is clicked(used as class name in example). Your problem arises as [**.css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) add inline style attribute which has priority over CSS class.

*CSS*

```css
.d {
    background-color: white;
}
.d:hover, .clicked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

*Script*

```
$('.d').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.d').removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked')
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nx4CV/)

### OR

You can use `!important` with the `.d:hover` class

*CSS*

```css
.d:hover{
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXLVS/)